# How to rename primary key constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, rename

I have a PK constraint on table `Notes` named `PK_dbo.Notes` and want to rename it to `PK_Notes` using SQL Server DDL, i.e. not by using SSMS rename menu option.

Mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729204/how-do-i-rename-my-constraints)'s answers queries don't work for me. [That thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712875/sql-server-rename-a-constraint)'s answers are also helpful, but don't work too.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sometimes you need to explicitly wrap names in square brackets, like this:

```
sp_rename @objname = N'[Notes].[PK_dbo.Notes]', @newname = N'PK_Notes'
```

I think it's because of the dot in PK name.

Also, as you see, PK constraints don't need `@objtype = 'OBJECT'` to be specified.